# Indenting Category list

Tags: categories

I am using the get_categories() function combined with a foreach loop, to create a list of all the catgorys in a form. like so:

```
$args = array(
                'type'                     => 'post',
                'hide_empty'               => 0, //<--IMPORTANT!!
                'hierarchical'             => 1,
                'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
                'pad_counts'               => false );
                $categories = get_categories($args);
                foreach($categories as $category) { 
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo "<td>$category->name</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='$category->cat_ID'/></td>";
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
```

However, what I need is for all the sub categories to be indented, but I cannot work out how.

After looking at the documentation [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) it seems that $category->parent parameter, may be helpful, but I cannot get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to add the indents manually, WordPress supports indents for Category Drop Downs only.

Comment: Looks like a typical usecase for wp_list_categories. Why are you not using it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'pad_counts' => false
);
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 

    echo '<tr>';

    if($category->parent != 0){ // If this is a subcategory
        echo "<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;$category->name</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>$category->name</td>";
    }

    echo "<td><input type='text' name='$category->cat_ID'/></td>";
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted, if it's how you solved your problem.

Comment: I will do as soon as the waiting period is over.